# any way to delete part of database data file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would think that not but maybe I'm wrong.
I have large SQL Server 2012 database which I care only about records from last month. I know it's possible to split data file, but then can I throw away safely 
one part? or they're both necessary for database to function properly? 
I would think they are...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you should use [table partitioning](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/04/12/table-partitioning-in-sql-server/), which will allow you to easily throw away data from previous months.

But please be careful not to confuse free space inside a database file with free space on your hard disk. Reclaiming disk space (e.g. shrinking a data file) only to reuse it over the following month (e.g. as you collect data for that month) is quite pointless.

Partitioning can make it easy to manage and stabilize the database files without constantly playing this boring shrink/grow game. You can do it without partitioning, too, but partitioning makes it easier *and* makes it possible to remove large chunks of data without paying write penalties for every single row.

Comment: ok, but table partitioning is on table level, would need to go through each of big tables and do that. Not sure what happens when data in partitioned tables to get rid off have some references to other tables. Basically I would not want this database to grow back again. I assume there is no option for overwrite old data automatically like log files can do.

Comment: A partitioning scheme and function can be used against multiple tables. Yes, you’d have to run the commands multiple times. Deleting data that has references in other tables is no different with partitioning or without: you still have to delete it in the right order. With partitioning it can be quicker.